# Does the closure of natural numbers under addition need to be proven or is it an axiom?

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, natural-numbers

From the way content is written online I am having trouble discerning which properties of numbers require proof and which are taken to be axioms because so few take the time to explain anything from a more fundamental level.

What I see most often for an arbitrarily defined group (just picking a random letter) S containing a set (not necessarily with order) of natural numbers is that:

-integers are closed under addition

-integers are associative

-there exists the identity element

-that there is an inverse element

Now I could have sworn at some point that I was asked at least to prove the existence of an identity element within a set of natural numbers a long time ago in precalculus, but because these statements are bunched together so often, I have to ask: are these statements taken to be self-evident among mathematicians or must they be constructed from a more fundamental level?

Comment: How are you defining the integers? If you go via the Peano Postulates for natural numbers addition has to be defined and its properties proved, and this is regularly done.

Comment: I asked a professor and they literally told me a set of natural numbers is defined as simply observing the set {0,1,2,3...}, and I don't know if that is correct or not. But from that, I suppose I could see proving the before mentioned statements.

Comment: It depends on the definitions and axioms you are using for defining and constructing the integers.  This probably needs to be proven if you are using the Peano Postulates.  But if this is a basic intro number theory or high school algebra or even abstract algebra (where you are told the integers are an additive group) then it is probably part of the definition/axioms.  So... depends on the context.

Comment: The context is more intro, but what is odd about Peano Postulates is that they take the identity element to be proven, whereas otherwise it wasn't an axiom and I had to prove it exists, so...is Peano really the most fundamental level from which to prove closure?

Comment: "I asked a professor and they literally told me a set of natural numbers is defined as simply observing the set {0,1,2,3...}, and I don't know if that is correct or not. "  It's not incorrect.  It's a great simplification (It basically "the natural numbers will be assumed to be given and clear" which is fine in certain contexts) and clearly the you can take addition being closed as a definition.

Comment: The alternative to Peano is to define an infinite cyclic Algebraic Group.  Then *by definition* addition is closed.

Comment: So from that set S={0,1,2,3...}, it *seems* obvious that natural numbers are closed under addition, but *seems like* isn't a proof, so then do I have to then define an operation such that (S1,S2)=S1+S2? Also, how would I write "This group S contains the set of numbers {0,1,2,3...}" as opposed to stating "{0,1,2,3...} are elements of S"?

Comment: Peano does not take identity to be proven, because the Peano postulates do not contain any definition of addition. There is a candidate for the additive identity once addition is defined, but the only special property of "zero" in Peano is that it is unique in not being the successor of any other element of the set. That this element is the identity for addition as subsequently defined requires proof.

Comment: Okay, thank you. <insert remaining characters>